# Changing datagridview row color on condition vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have loaded the data from database to datagridview and have two columns target value and volume where Item Unit >Item min value that volume cell should be in green color and Item min < Item Unit then volume should be in red color. I tried it but I am not able to do it.

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class view_all

```
Dim con1 As SqlConnection

Dim con As String  

Dim da As SqlDataAdapter

Dim ds As DataSet

Private Sub view_all_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim obj As New config

    con1 = New SqlConnection

    con1 = obj.getcontion()

    con1.Open()



    da = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from item", con1)

    ds = New DataSet

    da.Fill(ds, "item")

    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds

    DataGridView1.DataMember = "item"



    DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Item Id"
    DataGridView1.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Item Name"
    DataGridView1.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Item Number"
    DataGridView1.Columns(3).HeaderText = "Item Propose"
    DataGridView1.Columns(4).HeaderText = "Item Unit "
    DataGridView1.Columns(5).HeaderText = "Item Max"
    DataGridView1.Columns(6).HeaderText = "Item min"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you need to do is grab the column index and then move through all the rows which means going through all cells in the specified column.

```
 Dim intR As Integer = Maintt.DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
 Dim jr as integer ' for the rows
  For jR = 1 To intR
 'Put condition here
    Maintt.DataGridView1.Item(4, jR).Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
  Next
```

This would be for your column 4
Now you have all the cells in this column where your conditions hold colored green.
Go again through this column, find the cells where the background is green,
get the row index and color all the cells in this row green.